# Click activates command twice

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface

I have just added Commands to my Buttons (so I can add shortcuts to my WPF App).

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton"
        Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
        Click="MyButton_Click" />
```

The app works fine with the shortcuts, but I noticed something annoying: when I click on one of these Buttons, the associated function gets called twice, once from the Click event and once from the CommandExecute.

```
private void MyCommandExecute(object param)
{
    MyFunction();
}

private void MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyFunction();
}
```

Is there a way to stop that, or do I have to check for that eventuality by myself in the code?

Comment: Add a "global" flag to check the connection status. If it is `true`, do not re-connect. When disconnected, set the flag to `false`.

Comment: I know I could do that, but it seems messy to me, which is why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use the Click event, use just the Command.

WPF Buttons are supposed to use one or the other, not both approaches at the same time (unless you want to do two different things at the same time when clicked).

Comment: You're welcome! Also, if you implement a `CanExecute` function for your Command, keep in mind that your Button will be disabled automatically if that function returns false.